# An error while choosing option from DialogResult

Tags: c#, messagebox

I am experiencing a problem while choosing <kbd>Yes</kbd> on my MessageBox with buttons <kbd>Yes</kbd> or <kbd>No</kbd>.

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

From line:

```
AddEntryWindow addWindow = new AddEntryWindow
    (this, storedAuth.UserName, storedAuth.Password);
```

I don't understand what's the problem since few lines after this, is the same statement. How can I fix this?

**Fixed**

```
private void tsmiAddEntry_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (storedAuth == null)
    {
        DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show
            ("You must log in before you add an entry." 
            + Environment.NewLine + "You want to authenticate?",
            "Information", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, 
            MessageBoxIcon.Information);

        if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            AuthenticationWindow authWindow = 
                new AuthenticationWindow();
            authWindow.ShowDialog();
            storedAuth = authWindow.Result;

            AddEntryWindow addWindow = new AddEntryWindow
                (this, storedAuth.UserName, storedAuth.Password);
            addWindow.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        AddEntryWindow addWindow = new AddEntryWindow
            (this, storedAuth.UserName, storedAuth.Password);
        addWindow.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look this statement 
if (storedAuth == null)

and you accessing property of a null object.  if it is necessary object  then assign value to this object then access UserName and Password.

this is reason of error.. you should not use storedAuth.UserName, storedAuth.Password) in the following statement. use some default value like "" or "Default"

AddEntryWindow addWindow = new AddEntryWindow
                        (`this, storedAuth.UserName, storedAuth.Password`);
                    addWindow.ShowDialog();

Answer (score 2):

You're accessing properties of `storedAuth`, but just above you checked that `storedAuth` is null, so this code is *guaranteed* to throw a `NullReferenceException`...

Comment: Jeez, you are right. I have misinterpreted my own question. I was suppose to open registration window.